# Filepond rendering incorrectly in Bootstrap 5 Project

Tags: filepond

Has anyone else experienced issues relating to Filepond rendering incorrectly with Bootstrap 5?[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lq1B.jpg)

I have the exact same code running in a BS4 project without any issues. I initially thought there was unclosed divs but after checking every container and even stripping all other code out and testing with a skeleton page it still renders incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by reverting back to a basic example provided by Rik on another post so there must have been some CSS conflicts but it is working fine now.